# Developing web-api on google cloud using C# .NET

Tags: google-cloud-platform

we are planning to create a web-api layer to mediate data between api layer and application itself. Question is if we choose Google cloud, can we develop the web-api using Visual Studio and C# or other alternatives are better to choose. None of us really had experience building web-api and use cloud host.

Comment: IMHO Better to do Azure if you are going with MS Stack, unless you have some other dependency on Google platform

Comment: Thank you for your honest opinion!

Answer (score 1):

.NET is supported because you can deploy a Compute Engine instance based on Windows Server 2008/2012 [images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#list_all_images).

For a wep-api layer I suggest you to build that on [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) platform instead of Compute Engine because App Engine scale automatically!

On App Engine you can use Java/Python/PHP and Go and build your web-api with [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/)!

If you need OAuth2... Cloud Endpoints just do it out-of-the-box :D

If you plan to do a "real-time" api you can add [Firebase](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.it/2014/10/welcome-firebase-to-google-cloud-platform.html) support!

Hope to see you app on GCP!